# php + selenium, how to get all <a href...> tags from one page

Tags: php, testing, selenium

i've got a question, regarding selenium + php (using PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase):

i'm going through a loop, trying to get all  elements from a webpage, by doing something like:

```
 $i = 1;
 while ( $this->isElementPresent("//a[" . $i . "]")) {
      $tagContents = $this->getText("//a[" . $i . "]");
      print $tagContents . "\n";
      $i++;
 }
```

and it's not finding all elements :(
if i try to get the contents via $this->getText() a very few are filled, some are empty, and the overall amount of tags is way less than i really have on my page

anyone got an idea what i might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful method in Selenium - `getAllLinks()`. Look [here](http://pear.php.net/package/Testing_Selenium/docs/latest/Selenium/Testing_Selenium.html#methodgetAllLinks).

> Returns the IDs of all links on the page. If a given link has no ID,
>   it will appear as "" in this array.

Instead of this you can get all links using javascript (look at `getElementsByTagName()` - [example](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/712764-how-getelementbytype-check-validation-using-javascript#post2834985)).

**EDIT**
OK, I have done it for you (I was working on something similar) ;)

```
$js = "function getAllLinks() {
           var links = window.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
           var contents = [];
           for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
               var link = links[i];
               var text = link.textContent;
               contents.push(text);
           }
           return contents;
       }
       getAllLinks();";
$links = $this->getEval($js);
```